# Identifying duplicate columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm an R newbie and am attempting to remove duplicate columns from a largish dataframe (50K rows, 215 columns).  The frame has a mix of discrete continuous and categorical variables.

My approach has been to generate a table for each column in the frame into a list, then  use the `duplicated()` function to find rows in the list that are duplicates, as follows:

```
age=18:29
height=c(76.1,77,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7,79.9,81.1,81.2,81.8,82.8,83.5)
gender=c("M","F","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","M","F","M")
testframe = data.frame(age=age,height=height,height2=height,gender=gender,gender2=gender)

tables=apply(testframe,2,table)
dups=which(duplicated(tables))
testframe <- subset(testframe, select = -c(dups))
```

This isn't very efficient, especially for large continuous variables.  However, I've gone down this route because I've been unable to get the same result using summary (note, the following assumes an original `testframe` containing duplicates):

```
summaries=apply(testframe,2,summary)
dups=which(duplicated(summaries))
testframe <- subset(testframe, select = -c(dups))
```

If you run that code you'll see it only removes the first duplicate found. I presume this is because I am doing something wrong.  Can anyone point out where I am going wrong or, even better, point me in the direction of a better way to remove duplicate columns from a dataframe?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do with `lapply`:

```
testframe[!duplicated(lapply(testframe, summary))]
```

`summary` summarizes the distribution while ignoring the order.

Not 100% but I would use digest if the data is huge:

```
library(digest)
testframe[!duplicated(lapply(testframe, digest))]
```

Comment: In addition to @kohske 's suggestion to use `digest`, it might suffice to use `c` instead of `summary` as the `lapply` function.

Comment: It should be noted that summary for character vectors will produce the same summary even though they are different. This is because summary on a character vector only outputs the vector's length

Answer (score 34):

How about:

```
testframe[!duplicated(as.list(testframe))]
```

Comment: This is by far the fastest method I've used for testing for dups on a data.frame

Answer (score 11):

A nice trick that you can use is to transpose your data frame and then check for duplicates.

```
duplicated(t(testframe))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unique(testframe, MARGIN=2)
```

does not work, though I think it should, so try

```
as.data.frame(unique(as.matrix(testframe), MARGIN=2))
```

or if you are worried about numbers turning into factors,

```
testframe[,colnames(unique(as.matrix(testframe), MARGIN=2))]
```

which produces

```
   age height gender
1   18   76.1      M
2   19   77.0      F
3   20   78.1      M
4   21   78.2      M
5   22   78.8      F
6   23   79.7      F
7   24   79.9      M
8   25   81.1      M
9   26   81.2      F
10  27   81.8      M
11  28   82.8      F
12  29   83.5      M
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably best for you to first find the duplicate column names and treat them accordingly (for example summing the two, taking the mean, first, last, second, mode, etc... To find the duplicate columns:

```
names(df)[duplicated(names(df))]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just:

```
unique.matrix(testframe, MARGIN=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just would need to invert the duplicated-result in your code and could stick to using `subset` (which is more readable compared to bracket notation imho)

```
require(dplyr)
iris %>% subset(., select=which(!duplicated(names(.))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple command that would work if the duplicated columns of your data frame had the same names:

```
testframe[names(testframe)[!duplicated(names(testframe))]]
```

Comment: Can you share your code? Then we could have a look and try to find a solution. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that dataframes have been merged one time too many using, for example:

```
    testframe2 <- merge(testframe, testframe, by = c('age'))
```

It is also good to remove the .x suffix from the column names. I applied it here on top of Mostafa Rezaei's great answer:

```
    testframe2 <- testframe2[!duplicated(as.list(testframe2))]
    names(testframe2) <- gsub('.x','',names(testframe2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this Q&A is a popular Google search result but the answer is a bit slow for a large matrix I propose a new version using exponential search and data.table power.

This a function I implemented in dataPreparation package.

**The function**

`dataPreparation::which_are_bijection`

```
which_are_in_double(testframe)
```

Which return 3 and 4 the columns that are duplicated in your example

**Build a data set with wanted dimensions for performance tests**

```
age=18:29
height=c(76.1,77,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7,79.9,81.1,81.2,81.8,82.8,83.5)
gender=c("M","F","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","M","F","M")
testframe = data.frame(age=age,height=height,height2=height,gender=gender,gender2=gender)

for (i in 1:12){
  testframe = rbind(testframe,testframe)  
}
# Result in 49152 rows
for (i in 1:5){
  testframe = cbind(testframe,testframe)  
}
# Result in 160 columns
```

**The benchmark**
To perform the benchmark, I use the library `rbenchmark` which will reproduce each computations 100 times

```
benchmark(
  which_are_in_double(testframe, verbose=FALSE),
  duplicated(lapply(testframe, summary)),
  duplicated(lapply(testframe, digest))
)
```

```
                                             test replications elapsed
3           duplicated(lapply(testframe, digest))          100  39.505
2          duplicated(lapply(testframe, summary))          100  20.412
1 which_are_in_double(testframe, verbose = FALSE)          100  13.581
```

So which are bijection 3 to 1.5 times faster than other proposed solutions.

**NB 1:** I excluded from the benchmark the solution `testframe[,colnames(unique(as.matrix(testframe), MARGIN=2))]` because it was already 10 times slower with 12k rows.

**NB 2:** Please note, the way this data set is constructed we have a lot of duplicated columns which reduce the advantage of exponential search. With just a few duplicated columns, one would have much better performance for `which_are_bijection` and similar performances for other methods.