# Removing all but one duplicated column with same name R

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I've got a data table with about 200 column names in it, however, I have several columns which are repeated and are exactly the same in all respects, i.e they have the same name and same entries.

I want to get rid of all but one of these duplicated columns.

Take for instance:

```
Code         AEE       AEE      Code      AEE    EPI       Code     AEPI
20/09/1991  4562.43 108.13  20/09/1991  2017698 60.16   20/09/1991  18309
23/09/1991  4578.89 108.52  23/09/1991  2017698 56.55   23/09/1991  18309
24/09/1991  4578.89 108.52  24/09/1991  2017698 58.36   24/09/1991  18309
25/09/1991  4631.04 109.76  25/09/1991  2017698 56.55   25/09/1991  18309
26/09/1991  4665.34 110.57  26/09/1991  2017698 58.36   26/09/1991  18309
```

As you can see the Code column repeats every so often.

Doing: `Data[, Code := NULL]` only gets rid of the first "Code" and not the others.

Ideally the output would look like:

```
    Code       AEE   AEE     AEE     EPI    AEPI
20/09/1991  4562.43 108.13  2017698 60.16   18309
23/09/1991  4578.89 108.52  2017698 56.55   18309
24/09/1991  4578.89 108.52  2017698 58.36   18309
25/09/1991  4631.04 109.76  2017698 56.55   18309
26/09/1991  4665.34 110.57  2017698 58.36   18309
```

So only the first Code column remains. 
Thanks!

Comment: why do you have several columns with the same name in the first place?

Comment: It's just how the data arrived, not my choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Data <- Data[, !duplicated(lapply(Data, summary))]
```

Comment: Hi Tim, when i run this code it only removes rows (100 of them) and doesn't change any of the columns. Is this how the code is supposed to work?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon I updated my answer to properly subset the data frame.

Comment: i get what the code is doing now, so it should be sub setting on all the false values, i.e those that aren't duplicates. However,  when i run this, Data isn't subsetted rather Data just becomes a logical vector. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon I think you copied my code incorrectly. I get a data frame when I use it.  You might be missing a comma.

Comment: OP has a `data.table` while you used a `data.frame`- hence the confusion- this what tags for... And I guess you've just copy/pasted this from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818125/identifying-duplicate-columns-in-an-r-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

You can delete by the column number:

```
Data[, c(4,7) := NULL]   

Data
#         Code     AEE    AEE     AEE   EPI  AEPI
#1: 20/09/1991 4562.43 108.13 2017698 60.16 18309
#2: 23/09/1991 4578.89 108.52 2017698 56.55 18309
#3: 24/09/1991 4578.89 108.52 2017698 58.36 18309
#4: 25/09/1991 4631.04 109.76 2017698 56.55 18309
#5: 26/09/1991 4665.34 110.57 2017698 58.36 18309
```

Comment: I think referring to columns by their number is discouraged.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I do not know that. Do you have any reference for support?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13383995/5977215) has a reference to it, and [data.table FAQ 1.1](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html)

Comment: @SymbolixAU I agree it's not a good practice to use column numbers as that obfuscate your intention but the data shown here is under rare circumstances and legally should not happen. This is just an option to deal with the edge case.

Comment: I agree, there is a time and a place, but thought it worth noting.

Comment: I think the problem with this answer that it is not programmatic. OP has 200 columns from which he wants to remove duplicated columns problematically- not by eyeballing and then removing by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
df <- df[,!duplicated(names(df))]
```

OR

```
df <- df[,unique(names(df))]
```