# Consolidate duplicate columns and concatenate column names

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I'm sure this must be a duplicate. Say I have this:

```
stage <- seq(1,3,1)
exp1 <- c("A","B","C")
exp2 <- c("A","B","C")
exp3 <- c(NA, "B","C")
exp4 <- c("D","B","C")
exp5 <- c("A","B","C")
exp6 <- c(NA, "B","C")

df <- data.frame(stage, exp1, exp2, exp3, exp4, exp5, exp6)

  stage exp1 exp2 exp3 exp4 exp5 exp6
1     1    A    A <NA>    D    A <NA>
2     2    B    B    B    B    B    B
3     3    C    C    C    C    C    C
```

I want to combine all duplicated columns and show this by concatenating the column names. I can find duplicated columns [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818125/identifying-duplicate-columns-in-an-r-data-frame):

```
df[duplicated(lapply(df, summary))]

exp2 exp5 exp6
1    A    A <NA>
2    B    B    B
3    C    C    C
```

But I can't figure out how to combine the duplicated column names such that I get something like this:

```
  stage exp1_exp2_exp5 exp3_exp6 exp4
1     1              A      <NA>    D
2     2              B         B    B
3     3              C         C    C
```

Perhaps (probably) this is a poor way to visualize a comparison between different "exp"s? Maybe I need to reshape to show this more clearly?

Comment: How is `exp3` duplicate of `exp5`, but not of `exp1` or `exp2`?

Comment: Ah major mistake sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With base R, you can use `match` on the unique set of vectors in the data.frame to get the groupings, feed this to `split`, with the names of the variables as the first argument to break up the names by group, use `sapply`and `paste` to concatenate the variable names in each group, and then use `setNames` to provide the names to the unique set of columns.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(unique(as.list(df))),
         sapply(split(names(df), match(as.list(df), unique(as.list(df)))),
                paste, collapse="-"))
```

which returns

```
  stage exp1-exp2-exp5 exp3-exp6 exp4
1     1              A      <NA>    D
2     2              B         B    B
3     3              C         C    C
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -1) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarise(values = paste(sort(value), collapse = ',')) %>% 
  group_by(values) %>% 
  summarise(cols = paste(variable, collapse = '_')) %>% 
  separate_rows(values) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% gather(variable, value, -1, na.rm = TRUE), ., by = c('value'='values')) %>% 
  select(-variable) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  spread(cols, value)
```

which gives:

> ```
>   stage exp1_exp2_exp5 exp3_exp6 exp4
> 1     1              A      <NA>    D
> 2     2              B         B    B
> 3     3              C         C    C
> ```

Comment: Although this is not exactly what I was after it does provide a different approach which will be very useful to me. So thank you.

Comment: Ah it is now. However, I still like the first answer that you gave because it groups "exp"s by common groups of letters. I can still get code from the edits page.

Comment: Updated. Now it gives the correct output, though @lmo's solution is a lot shorter.

Comment: @Pete900 If you run my code step by step, you'll see that it groups *"exp"*s by common groups of letters as well ;-)