# Display identical columns in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Suppose I have the following dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),B=c("a","b","c"),C=c(2,1,3),D=c(1,2,3),E=c("a","b","c"),F=c(1,2,3))

> df
  A B C D E F
1 1 a 2 1 a 1
2 2 b 1 2 b 2
3 3 c 3 3 c 3
```

I want to filter out the columns that are identical. I know that I can do it with

```
DuplCols <- df[duplicated(as.list(df))]
UniqueCols <- df[ ! duplicated(as.list(df))]
```

In the real world my dataframe has more than 500 columns and I do not know how many identical columns of the same kind I have and I do not know the names of the columns. However, each columnname is unique (as in `df`). My desired result is (optimally) a dataframe where in each row the column names of the identical columns of one kind are stored. The number of columns in the `DesiredResult` dataframe is the maximal number of identical columns of one kind in the original dataframe and if there are less identical columns of another kind, `NA` should be stored:

```
> DesiredResult
  X1   X2   X3
1  A    D    F
2  B    E   NA
3  C   NA   NA
```

(With "identical column of the same kind" I mean the following: in `df` the columns `A`, `D`, `F` are identical columns of the same kind and `B`, `E` are identical columns of the same kind.)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9818125/4137985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique` and then test with `%in%` where it matches to extract the `colname`.

```
tt_lapply(unique(as.list(df)), function(x) {colnames(df)[as.list(df) %in% list(x)]})
tt
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "D" "F"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "B" "E"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "C"

t(sapply(tt, "length<-", max(lengths(tt)))) #As data.frame
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "A"  "D"  "F" 
#[2,] "B"  "E"  NA  
#[3,] "C"  NA   NA
```